# How to get the matrix of image in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get matrix of image in imageview.
like imageviewtransform:

```
CGAffineTransform currentTransform = _dicomImageView.transform;
```

Comment: What exactly do you need here? Some transform may be applied which is computed from the UIImage orientation. But after that it depends on the view content mode (scale aspect fit, center...). I think those do not use a transform but rather compute the frame in which the image should be drawn. But both are possible.

Comment: I need to implement a function that draws a line on UIImageview. When zooming in or out, UIImageview changes the length of the line, but the width of the line does not change, that is, I need to find the corresponding relationship between the point on the screen and the point on the image

Comment: If you are using a scroll view you can do that by combining a scroll view offset and the scroll view zoom scale. But you are still missing some information on your issue. Like should the line width depend on the image view initial size or the actual image size. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: I am doing a product for medical use, and the doctor can draw a line on the image, but the two endpoints of the line must be the same as the endpoint on the image when the image is magnified. That is to say no matter how I can not shift the zoom at the beginning of the corresponding point on the corresponding image. You can go to the App Store to download a dicom app, I just want to achieve similar to the kind of drawing function.